# Can I insert a Document into Lucene without generating a TokenStream?

Tags: lucene, indexing, scoring

Is there a way to add a document to the index by supplying terms and term frequencies directly, rather than via Analysis and/or TokenStream?  I ask because I want to model some data where I know the term frequencies, but there is no underlying text document to be analyzed.  I could create one by repeating the same term many times (I don't care about positions or highlighting in this case, either, just scoring), but that seems a bit perverse (and probably slower than just supplying the counts directly).

(also asked on the mailing list)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing using Solr (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17996604/specifying-multivalued-term-frequency-in-solr-update). Did femtoRgon's answer below turn out to be the best solution for you?

Comment: I think it will be the best way, but I haven't implemented yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At any rate, you don't need  to pass everything through an Analyzer in order to create the document.  I'm not aware of any way to pass in Terms and Frequencies as you've asked (though I'd be interested to know if you find a good approach to it), but you can certainly pass in `IndexableFields` one term at a time.  That would still require you to add each term multiple times, like:

```
IndexableField field = new StringField(fieldName, myTerm, FieldType.TYPE_NOT_STORED);
for (int i = 0; i < frequency; i++) {
    document.add(field);
}
```

You can also take a step further back, and cut the `Document` class out entirely, by using any `Iterable<IndexableField>`, a simple `List`, for instance, which might suffice for a more  direct approach for modelling your data.

Not sure if that gets you any closer to what you are looking for, but perhaps a step vaguely in the right direction.

Comment: Yes that seems like the best approach given the standard public Lucene API.  Anything more direct seems to involve rooting around in some fairly low-level methods.  It would be something like: define a new IndexingChain, pass it in as part of IndexWriterConfig.  Then in the chain, define a different kind of DocFieldConsumer that handles special fields in a special way.